# How to copy files from one drive to adls using logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate, azure-logic-app-standard, power-automate-custom-connector

my logic app trigger action is when an http request is received. after that there is share point action is there name is get file content. so here i want to add parallel branch with action name is get file content(ONE DRIVE) action. here the main problem is while i add one drive action it will ask sign in but my project id did not have Microsoft so how can i sign in one drive action and how can i copy onedrive file to adls

basically i'm struck how to processed these task . how to sign in one drive with out Microsoft id . my project did not have Microsoft id

Comment: You need to have credentials to login to one drive connector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have credentials to make a connection between logic app workflow and One drive :

[image]

If no credentials then you cannot use the one drive connector

Comment: is these possible to move onedrive files to sharepoint automatically

Comment: or is these possible to give one drive location manually like share action(get file content)